# ¿Cómo regreso al titulo original luego de usar useEffect para cambiar el titulo en un componente - Reactjs?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router-dom, useeffect

¿Cómo hago para que el titulo de la pagina regrese al estado original? Use `useEffect`en mi componente `Pagetwo.jsx` para cambiar el titulo y no regresa al titulo original en el componente `App.js`, es donde ahí establecí las rutas

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
    import Pagetwo from './Pagetwo.jsx'
    
    function App(){
       return(
          <Router>
             <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact>
                   <div>Pagina Principal...</div>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/paginasecundaria">
                   <Pagetwo/>
                </Route>
             </Switch>
          </Router>
       )
    }
```

y en el componente `Pagetwo.jsx` este es el código:

```
    import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
    const Pagetwo = () =>{
    useEffect(() =>{
       document.title= `Pagina Secundaria`
    }, [])        
    return(
      <>
         <div>Code...</div>
         <Link to="/"> Volver a Inicio</Link>
      </>        
    )}
```

voy a la ruta`/paginasecundaria` y renderiza todo incluso el titulo pero al darle click en `Volver a Inicio` , no se cambia el titulo por el original en `index.html` > `<title>Pagina Principal</title>`

Comment: Si necesitas manejar el título de forma dinámica, tienes que construir un componente que reciba como parámetro el título.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo diría, si no me equivoco que és porque react trabaja sin refrescar la página, entonces al cambiar el título del documento y posteriormente volver al componente principal no se cambia.

Para que me entiendas tendrías que decirle en la página principal que te cambie el título al original. React trabaja con componentes pero sobre el mismo html principal para no refrescar la página, y al cambiar este se queda en todos los componentes.

Una solución podría ser:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Pagetwo from './Pagetwo.jsx'

const PaginaPrincipal = () => {
 useEffect(() =>{
   document.title= `Pagina Principal`
 }, []);     

 return <div>Pagina Principal...</div>;
}

function App(){
   return(
      <Router>
         <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact>
               <PaginaPrincipal />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/paginasecundaria">
               <Pagetwo/>
            </Route>
         </Switch>
      </Router>
   )
}
```

Aunque lo ideal sería hacer otro componente para la página principal. Es decir en un documento aparte.

Espero te sirva de ayuda, cuaquier cosa contestame y respondo.